# Docker Desktop not starting

Tags: docker

Docker desktop was working fine but after a reboot the docker desktop doesn't start at all.

I've tried switchDaemon, Switch to Windows container etc., but none of them starts.

I'm using WSL2 and all my containers are linux based. If I re-install then I'll lose all data and images.

```
wsl --list
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
Ubuntu-20.04 (Default)
docker-desktop
docker-desktop-data
```

Every restart attempt results with the following log entires.

```
open \\.\pipe\dockerProcd: The system cannot find the file specified.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Log:

```
[2022-08-01T14:09:47.861542400Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (15e5c8d5) 4b373d33-BackendAPI S->C DockerDesktopElectron POST /nps (1.6312ms): OK
[2022-08-01T14:09:50.286711200Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (e474d45c) 4b373d33-BackendAPI S<-C DockerDesktopElectron POST /analytics/track
[2022-08-01T14:09:50.287235200Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (e474d45c) 4b373d33-BackendAPI S<-C DockerDesktopElectron bind: {"body":null,"event":"actionMenuSwitchWindowsDaemon"}
[2022-08-01T14:09:50.287758600Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] (e474d45c) 4b373d33-BackendAPI S->C DockerDesktopElectron POST /analytics/track (1.0474ms): OK
[2022-08-01T14:09:50.288277300Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] Usage statistics: actionMenuSwitchWindowsDaemon
[2022-08-01T14:09:50.288277300Z][com.docker.backend.exe][I] anonymous remaining time: 23h35m58.7117227s
[2022-08-01T14:09:51.767785100Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (3f58fd7b) acc5d626-CSharpAPI S<-C DockerDesktopElectron POST /desktop/switch-engine
[2022-08-01T14:09:51.773786400Z][IPCServer         ][Info   ] (3f58fd7b) acc5d626-CSharpAPI S->C DockerDesktopElectron POST /desktop/switch-engine (6ms): OK
[2022-08-01T14:09:53.056235800Z][WslKeepAlive      ][Info   ] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.


[2022-08-01T14:09:53.059234500Z][WslKeepAlive      ][Info   ] wsl keep-alive stopped
[2022-08-01T14:09:53.059234500Z][WslKeepAlive      ][Warning] stopped unexpectedly
[2022-08-01T14:09:53.244964600Z][vpnkit-bridge.exe][W] windows: still waiting for dns-forwarder, volume-contents, lifecycle-server, wsl2-bootstrap-expose-ports, devenv-volumes, procd, docker, debug-shell, diagnosticd, wsl2-cross-distro-service, log after 10.01406s
[2022-08-01T14:10:03.238970300Z][vpnkit-bridge.exe][W] windows: still waiting for dns-forwarder, volume-contents, lifecycle-server, wsl2-bootstrap-expose-ports, devenv-volumes, procd, docker, debug-shell, diagnosticd, wsl2-cross-distro-service, log after 20.0080657s
[2022-08-01T14:10:05.610766100Z][com.docker.backend.exe][W] 526c5971-PauseHDL /pause/events server not replying: Get "http://ipc/pause/events": open \\.\pipe\dockerProcd: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2022-08-01T14:10:13.241610100Z][vpnkit-bridge.exe][W] windows: still waiting for lifecycle-server, wsl2-bootstrap-expose-ports, devenv-volumes, procd, docker, dns-forwarder, volume-contents, wsl2-cross-distro-service, log, debug-shell, diagnosticd after 30.0105872s
```

Comment: Have you tried shutdown wsl `wsl --shutdown` and start again `wsl`